# 2 Sum Problem Using Binary Search - Condition for Correct Solution

Tags: python, algorithm

I took a solution from https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs9/sample_probs/TwoSum.pdf for solving the 2-sum problem in less than quadratic time by ordering the input array and using binary search. The code is ported to Python as that is the language I am most familiar with.

I'm a little bit suspicious abut the code. The comment about "If this points at us, then the pair exists only if there is another copy of the element. Look ahead of us and behind us." sounds authoritive, yet I can't see why it is not sufficient that `i` and `compliment_idx` are different. (The problem requires that the two summands be distinct.)

Any clarification please? Also, is the the solution otherwise correct?

```
def binary_search(lst, target):
    low = 0
    high = len(lst) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if lst[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif lst[mid] > target:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return None


def two_sum_binary_search(arr, total):
    length = len(arr)
    arr = sorted(arr)
    for i in range(length):
        compliment = total - arr[i]
        compliment_idx = binary_search(arr, compliment)
        if compliment_idx is not None:  # Found solution!
            """ 
            If this points at us, then the pair exists only if
            there is another copy of the element. Look ahead of
            us and behind us.
            """
            # Why is it not sufficient that i and compliment_idx are different?
            if compliment_idx != i or (i > 0 and arr[i - 1] == arr[i]) or (i < length - 1 and arr[i + 1] == arr[i]):
                return (i, compliment_idx)
    return None


assert two_sum_binary_search([1, 2, 3], 4) == (0, 2)
assert two_sum_binary_search([1234, 5678, 9012], 14690) == (1, 2)
assert two_sum_binary_search([2, 2, 3], 4) == (0, 1)
```

Comment: This function return `(0, 0)` for `print(two_sum_binary_search([2, 2], 4))`. Is that correct output?

Comment: No, that is incorrect output. The extra checks break the algorithm it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it is sufficient here. This is because `compliment_idx` is a deterministic function of `compliment` (really those should be s/compliment/complement/g). If we're in a multiple-copy situation, the value of `compliment_idx` will be the same for each, so another copy will satisfy `compliment_idx != i`. Hypothetically if the search were not deterministic, we'd need the additional searches implemented by the given code.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean about the non-deterministic search, but the main point is the extra checks don't appear to be needed. In fact, as @גלעד ברקן pointed out, they make the code give the wrong output of `(0, 0)` for `print(two_sum_binary_search([2, 2], 4))` so they must go! Strange that the comment in the code seems so confident...